# Material-ui Toggle labels, how can I have a left, right and top label?

Tags: css, html, material-ui

I am trying to make a toggle switch which has a label positioned on each side of the toggle and a label on top.

E.g. I'm trying to make a left/right switch.

Out put would look like this.

Side

Left [Toggle] Right

This is the toggle code:

```html
<Toggle
  floatingLabelText="Side"
  label="Side"
  labelPosition="right"
  style={styles.toggle}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to set both labels (right and left) at the same time in Toggle component.

What I have done is a workaround to this problem is by doing this kind of code:

```
<div>
    <label>Option 1</label>
    <Toggle 
        label="Option 2" 
        labelPosition="right"
        style={{margin : '-20px 0px 0px 60px'}} 
        defaultToggled={false} 
        onToggle={function(event: object, isInputChecked: bool)}
    />
</div>
```

Please Note: You can change this 'style={{margin : '-20px 0px 0px 60px'}}' as per your desired place ment.

Answer (score 1):

Material UI only supports a Left OR right side label. You'll have to use HTML and CSS to position the labels to the other two positions.

In this case I'd suggest not using the label property at all and just enclosing the Toggle in a div with some spans to show the appropriate text.